# HTML parsing using Python's HTMLParser

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am parsing through HTML code using Python, and would like a function that returns a list of names.

The HTML I'm looking for is formatted like this:

```
<input type=hidden name=user value="msmith">
```

Every time "type=hidden" and "name=user", I would like "msmith" to be included in the list of exported names.

The code must be portable, and can't include 3rd party libraries such as beautifulSoup. Preferably, it would use `HTMLParser`.

Comment: show in question your code and full error message (Traceback)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer BeautifulSoup. You can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
hidden_tags = soup.find_all("input", type="hidden")
for tag in hidden_tags:
    # tag.name is the name and tag.value the value, simple isn't it ?
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to use 3rd party libraries for this. I'm writing a tool for people to use on machines that don't have beautiful soup installed.